# opening files in parallel using threading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python, with no experience with multi-threading, but I have some code that would benefit from the application of threads. I found a basic example and modified it with the intent of having each thread open a file and then process its contents. The only problem is, the execution hangs in `do_work()` when attempting to open the file

```
import threading
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()
lock = threading.Lock()

#assuming these files exist
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']

def do_work(item):
    with lock:
        print(item)    #will print file path
    
    with open(item) as fh:
        #but execution never reaches here
        src = fh.read()
        #do stuff with source

def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()

for i in range(4):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for f in files:
    q.put(f)    #fill q with file paths to be opened in parallel

q.join()    #block until all tasks are complete
```

I have a working solution where each file is opened in serial on the main thread then processed on separate threads, but ideally, each file path in the queue should be opened, read and processed by its own thread.

Comment: This code runs fine for me in Python3.3. I renamed `file` as `fh` and  added `content=fh.read();print(str(item) + " contains: " + str(content))` to the do_work function. Why don't you make sure you are not hanging in that part of your code?

Comment: Works fine for me too.  Well, other than the try: statement needing a `pass` to not throw an indentation error, but yeah.

Comment: @riza as it turns out the program hangs in `do_work()` function, when I try to open the file, I've updated the code

Comment: works for me with python3.3

Answer (score 1):

it works for me in python 3.3

i guess you have an error in `do_work` that (1) is not being logged and (2) means that `task_done` is not being called.

so change:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()
```

to

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        try:
            do_work(item)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            q.task_done()
```

you don't *need* the `except` (it's just to print something that may help) but the `finally` is critical, or the `q.join()` will never exit when you have an error.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.2, you think that could be the issue?

Comment: did you try what i suggested?

Comment: yes, but there is no exception and no output of any kind, but if I comment out the `with open(item) as fh:` block it runs properly

Comment: then i guess it's hanging in `do stuff with source`.  or the indentation above is not the same as your code.  have you tried copying the code in your question and running it, to check?  maybe there's a difference between what is shown here and what you are using.  it is very unlikely to be a problem with python 3.2 v 3.3.